# API Gateway: ANY /{proxy+} not catching requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

As I understand it, if I create a ressource as `/{proxy+}` with an `ANY` method it should catch `/`, `/pages` and `/pages/123/image`?

Although it doesn't seem so. What could I be doing wrong?

The integration is a Lambda function, and when I test it everything looks fine.
I have deployed the API.

```
"/{proxy+}": {
  "x-amazon-apigateway-any-method": {
    "produces": [
      "application/json"
    ],
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "proxy",
        "in": "path",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "responses": {},
    "security": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought a `/{proxy+}` ressource could be used to catch requests to other ressources and do validation etc, but if another ressource matches the request, it takes precedence over `{proxy+}`.